# make a delay in my vector, matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, delay

I have vector for example. Ones and zeros are representing traffic and idle states for base station traffic.

```
     u=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

I know how to calculate number of ones and zeros in it after each break. 
But I need help for delay. Zeros are telling me when I can put my base station in sleep mode.
Is there a way to make a delay for example that, base station does not go to sleep after first zero, instead of that that it goes to sleep after third zero, that means with some kind o delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming [ASantosRibeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24079910/2338750) interpreted your question correctly, you could do this to find when to "go to sleep":

```
delay = 3;    
idx = find(diff(u)==-1) + delay
idx =
     8    20    32    43
```

This is assuming you want a delay of 3.

`diff(u)` returns the difference between consecutive elements in `u`. Finding when the difference equals `-1` is equivalent to finding the indices of when the light changes from 1 to 0. By adding the `delay`, you have your desired indices.

Comment: That would be right if he wanted the system to go to sleep 3 time points after any zero. but if instead he wants to be sure that at least 3 consecutive zeros exist, than that simple way does not work. check this. u=[1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ];
idx = find(diff(u)==-1) + 3

Comment: I also managed to do this on harder way before you helped me

          **no_of_values_nodelay=(find(u~=[u(2:end), u(end)+1]));**
           **values_nodelay=no_of_values_nodelay(1:2:end);** 
           **l=1;**
           **delay1=2;**
           **values_delay1=[];**
             **while l<=length(values_nodelay)**
             ** values_delay1_temp=values_nodelay(l)+delay1;**
             **values_delay1=[values_delay1, values_delay1_temp];**
             **l=l+1;**
             **end**
             **values_delay1**

it works and give same results ! !

Answer (score 2):

Not a simple solution but yet I think you should find it interesting. You can optimize from here.
First of all I assumed you wanted to go to sleep after the third consecutive 0.
Check the example.

CODE:

```
u=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ];
bw_u=bwlabel(u==0);

get_breaks=bsxfun(@eq, bw_u, unique(bw_u)');
pos_break=cumsum(get_breaks,2).*get_breaks;
third_0=pos_break(2:end,:)==3;

[~,indx_third_0]=find(third_0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
indx_third_0 =

     8
    20
    32
    43
```

Answer (score 1):

Again assuming [ASantosRibeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24079910/2586922) interpreted your question correctly, you can do it a little more simply as follows. Let `n` denote the desired number of zeros. In your case, `n=3`;

```
>> ind = find(diff(conv(2*u-1, repmat(-1, [1 n])) == n) == 1) + 1
ind =
     8    20    32    43
```